# LoaderCallbacks missed after rotation

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-support-library, android-loader, android-configchanges

I have this problem every time I use loader. If I start my `AsyncTaskLoader` and then rotate screen (doesn't matter one or several times) `onLoaderFinished()` is not called. `loadInBackground()` finishes its work but `onLoaderFinished()` is not called. It looks like callbacks are missed but in activity `onCreate()` I have:

```
LoaderManager lm = getSupportLoaderManager();
if (lm.getLoader(LOADER_FLIGHTS) != null) {
    lm.initLoader(LOADER_FLIGHTS, null, mFlightsLoaderCallbacks);
}
```

Doesn't matter callbacks are implemented by activity or field. In my case I use field:

```
LoaderCallbacks<SearchResult> mFlightsLoaderCallbacks = new LoaderCallbacks<SearchResult>() {
```

Sometimes it works pretty good but in some devices I have got this trouble again.

I searched in Android bugs tracker but found nothing useful.

Is this my mistake and how can I correct it?

**EDIT:**

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<SearchResult> loader, SearchResult res) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            dismissProgress(R.string.dlg_wait_flights);
        }
    });
    mResult = res;
    Helper.Log.d(TAG, "Loader.onLoadFinished.");
```

Comment: Your Activity _is_ the handler, or has a handler object? And are you sure it is not executed, or do you just not see the results?

Comment: @ClassStacker please look at updated code

Comment: Regarding your edit, this means that you do not see the log message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap your initLoader call in an if statement. In fact, I'm not even sure how initLoader is ever called if you are expecting the loader to not be null before you even call initLoader.

Comment: If I do this my loader will start immediately. What to do if I don't want this?

Comment: Okay, so you are saying you call initLoader somewhere else that you didn't include in your question. Are you retaining your fragment with setRetainInstance(true)?

Comment: Do you have any orientationChanges registered in your manifest?

Comment: Are you sure your initLoader call is being made after a rotate?

Comment: Have you looked into calling the method LoaderManager.restartLoader? This allows you to instruct your Loader to load its data again and (depending on the your Loader's implementation) when it's finished doing this, your onLoadFinished will be called.